# Adding a project reference to an android project

Tags: android

I am a C# developer and getting started with Android.  I am attempting to duplicate a couple applications I already have in VS.  The project is made of 2 executables and 1 common assembly.  The 2 executables contain the application specific logic while the common contains centralized forms and logic (such as login form).  I am using Eclipse.  So how can I accomplish this layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, with your project selected in the Navigation or Package Explorer view:

> Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path

Here you can add references to Libraries (jar files which I believe are similar in concept to C# assemblies) or other projects you have open in Eclipse.

So create as many projects in Eclipse as you want for your application's layout, and in the main Android project (the one where your application's Manifest file exists) reference those other projects, or the jar files you exported from those projects, in the Java Build Path.

Comment: I added the common project to the main project using a class folder, added couple classes, but I am not able to see my Common namespace nor classes in the common assembly

Comment: "Using a class folder"? That doesn't sound like what I said to do. :)  Also not quite sure what you mean by "common namespace" or "common assembly".  Those aren't Java terms, and I don't think the .NET definition of those terms map 1:1 to anything in Java.

Comment: I'm going to back up and say you really just need to read up on how the Java ClassPath works, and what .jar files are.  These are two extremely simple concepts and once you understand them you will understand what you can/can't do in Java to mimic your .NET project setup.